# Using JsonConverter Attribute to prevent Self Referencing Loop

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm getting the following error: "Self referencing loop detected for property 'DefaultAssignTo'"

Here's the class I'm trying to serialize:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(AccountConverter))]
    public virtual Account DefaultAssignTo { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultAssignToId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(OtherConverter))]
    public virtual Other Other { get; set; }
    public int? OtherId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string OtherName
    {
        get
        {
        return "Name = " + this.AccountName;
        }
}
}
```

I know I can prevent this with adding settings like below, but that causes problems when trying to deserialize.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
};
```

As you can see, I created a couple custom converters.  The one for the `Other` class works, but the one for the `Account` class never gets called.  I'm guessing that's because the by the time the ContractResolver gets to `DefaultAssignTo`, that is an `Account`, there is already a contract for `Account` so the custom converter is never used.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to make this custom converter work? (And how or point me to some information so I can figure it out.)

If the answer to #1 is not possible:

2. Is my guess why it's not working correct?
3. What are some alternatives?

Edit: (The use case I will eventually want to implement would be something like below)

An `Account` will be assigned to something. (For example a `Task`) When an `Account` creates a `Task`, if `DefaultAssignedTo` is not null, the `Task` is assigned to the value of `DefaultAssignedTo`.  `DefaultAssignedTo` can reference a different `Account` or the `Account` that contains `DefaultAssignedTo`.

So if there are two `Accounts` John and Jane where `DefaultAssignedTo` is set to John for both Accounts. When Jane creates a `Task` it will be assigned to John and when John creates a Task it will be assigned to John. Jane will serialize as expected, but John throws a self referencing loop exception.

Edit:
I should have made it clear that I don't expect or require `DefaultAssignedTo` to be a full serialization.  The purpose of the custom converter is to remove what causes the self referencing loop, but still serialize other data contained in `DefaultAssignedTo`.

Comment: Is there some way to get the Account object from just the ID? You can make `DefaultAssignTo` only getter that uses the ID provided to return the Account object, since it looks like you already serialize the ID